# How to store the entire table data in android?

Tags: android

I am storing my sqlite table data in arraylist. In my project I am getting the question and options of that question based on the question id. In my options database table I have 4 columns and 5 rows(since 5 options the number of rows=5)
column1: optionid
column2: quesid
column3: option_description
column4: answer

I am storing this table values in an arraylist. Now I need to pass the arraylist to other page. But in the arraylist only one row of the table is saving at a time. So I want to store all the rows in that arraylist. How can I do that?

My code:

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList3;
static ArrayList<String> optionlist;
query2 = "SELECT * FROM 'iapp_options' WHERE question_id = list1.get(0))+";";
stringList3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
stringList3 = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query2, null); 


 for (int i = 0; i < stringList3.size(); i++) {
    optionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    optionlist = stringList3.get(i);
}
```

Now when I am passing this optionlist array to other page the list is containing only the last row of the table. How to store all 5 rows data into that arraylist?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringList3.size(); i++) {
    optionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    optionlist = stringList3.get(i);
}
```

Every time you are making a new `ArrayList optionlist` and overwrite values on it. So you are getting only one ArrayList optionlist having last Values.

Why not you are just pass `stringList3` to other activity instead of using extra ArrayList..

Or fill complete optionlist with stringList3's all values..

```
optionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < stringList3.size(); i++) { 
for (int j = 0; j < stringList3.get(i).size(); j++)
    optionlist = stringList3.get(i).get(j);
}
```

Now this will cause your `optionlist` has all values form `stringList3` in a String format..

Hope you will understand it.

Thanks..

Comment: Hi actually for setting the options to textview I have taken new arraylist optionlist. I sent the stringlist3 to other page directly...thank you for the suggestion...

Comment: Hi in stringList3 array at a time only 1 row data is storing...how to store 4 rows data so that i can pass the entire stringlist3 array to other page with 4 rows in it?

Comment: query2 = "SELECT * FROM 'iapp_options' WHERE question_id= list1.get(0));
stringList3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
stringList3 = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query2, null); 
System.out.println("options in tringlist3"+stringList3);.....At a time stringList3 contains stringlist3[[1, 111, option1, 1], [2, 111, option2, 1], [3, 111, option3, 1], [4, 111, option4, 1], [5, 111, option5, 0]]

Comment: for same question 5 options...so when displaying the 1st question it is storing the 1st question options...for the second question it is displaying second question options and so on....when I am passing the stringlist3 arraylist to the new page so only the last question options are displaying....

Comment: The same mistake like previous. Your database query returns only one row and you are adding it a new stringList3. So only one row result in stringList3.

Comment: hi for each question there are 5 options na..so each time the query is displaying 5 rows of same question and those 5 rows are storing in the stringlist3. so every time it is displaying those 5 rows...but i want to store the options of the displayed number of questions?

Comment: list1.get(0) is this problem in your query? I think it should be list1.get(position) or any other variable which is changed on selected question..